# Play framework can't find javac

Tags: java, windows, playframework

I'm following a play tutorial when I run the web server before making any changes to the app. The server throws an error:

```
IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I check my JAVA_HOME  and it reads C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25. How would one fix this issue?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure that the `javac` is in the OS's search path

For example, on Windows, goto `Control Panel` -> `System`, click `Advanced System Settings`, click on `Environment Variables`.

In the `System variables`, locate the variable named `path` and insert **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`** at the start of the `value`.  Don't forget to add `;` between the values ;)

[image][image]

Click `Okay`, `Okay`.

Close any command prompt windows you have open and re-open them.  This will ensure that they are updated with the new environment variables.

Comment: Just a small correction: one should add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` to the path, not `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`.

Comment: did everything, still facing the same issue :(

Comment: Lol. It also helps to actually install the JDK too.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't aware that the typical java install **DOES NOT** have `javac`. Thus, I did the following:

1) Visited the [Java SE Development Kit site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

2) Downloaded the version for my Operating System and installed it

3) went to the root folder of the newly Java SE Development Kit (in this case `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin`)

4)Using the windows search, entered `environment variables`, which brings up the option `Edit the system environment variables` on Windows 7

5) clicked on `Environment Variables` in the System Properties tab that should have opened.

6) with `PATH` highlighted, clicked `Edit...`

7) Added `;`(a semi-colon to seperate this new path from the old) + `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin` (make sure there is no space between the semi-colon and the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check your system access. You should have all access power during the instalation or setting process. I just had to require full OS access (Windows, in the big company) to solve this issue and now it's all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might have the JDK bin directory in your `PATH` environment variable, this problem can occur. To fix it, put the path of JDK bin directory (not the JRE one) at the beginning of the PATH variable, just in case `javac` is getting picked up in the wrong directory because the wrong directory happens to be first.