# IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: scala, play2-mini

I got the error "IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" while running my scala project in play 2. why does this error occur . Please solve this problem.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455732/play-framework-cant-find-javac

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check that you have the environment variable JAVA_HOME defined and set to the root directory of your JDK (not just a JRE, which doesn't include javac)

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who googles this error when using xml beans (I was forced to maintain an old app that uses xmlbeans and got this error), use jdk 5 and not higher for xmlbeans and this error goes away

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml-beans command scomp, you can pun the option -compiler like -compiler "C:\jdk1.8.0.231\bin\javac.exe"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).