# IOException: Cannot run program "javac" when "sudo ./sbt/sbt compile" in Spark?

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I'm installing [Apache Spark](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/) which uses its own copy of SBT to set things up.

I'm using Linux Mint in a VirtualBox VM.

Here's a snippet from the error when I run `sudo ./sbt/sbt compile` from the Spark directory `spark-0.9.0-incubating`:

```
[error] (core/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": error=2, No such file or directory

[error] Total time: 181 s, completed Mar 9, 2014 12:48:03 PM
```

I can run `java` and `javac` from the command line just fine: e.g. `javac -version` gives `javac 1.6.0_31`

The correct `jdk1.6.0_31/bin` is in my `PATH`.

I read that the error might be due to the 64-bit JDK that I had installed, but I get the same error with the 32 bit JDK.

How can I sort out the issue?

edit: Using bash shell.

Comment: Did you set `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957486/ioexception-cannot-run-program-javac-createprocess-error-2-the-system-canno)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** I'm mostly guessing now and still am unsure I should've responding here rather than adding a comment. Until it's clear, the DISCLAIMER remains.

When you execute `java` and `javac` from the command line, what user are you at that moment? I'm pretty sure your problems surface because the users you operate **are** different.

Please notice that you're executing `sudo ./sbt/sbt compile` as `root` (due to the way `sudo` works), but you say nothing about what user(s) you've been using to execute `javac` and `java` commands.

Add `jdk1.6.0_31/bin` to `PATH` for `root` and you'll be all set (as far as the configuration of Java's concerned).

I'd also recommend setting `JAVA_HOME` to point to `jdk1.6.0_31` as it may help at times -- many applications are using it as the way to find the location of Java.

As a workaround, you may edit `./sbt/sbt` and add `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` appropriately.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is set for current user but I don't know if it is set for root. Any comment on how to see the `PATH` of the `root` user? `sudo echo $PATH` gives the same as `echo $PATH`.

Comment: It compiles with the workaround `sudo -E su` followed by `./sbt/sbt compile`

Comment: To set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables for a user, say `root`, you need to edit the user's profile files, say `.bashrc` or something similar that depends on the shell. Without it, you're going to struggle with missing variables and hence the issue you're facing. I edited the answer to offer a workaround (it's **a workaround*, though).

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the `javac` executable. To do this in Ubuntu please run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It also places it within your `path` variable.